# Can a fragment extend a fragment activity? [Android]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have created a MainActivity which consists of 3 tabs which are scrollable (by using ViewPager). Now each of these 3 tabs is a Fragment. Also, I am using ActionBarSherlock (ABS).

For the 1st Fragment, I have created the following class:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return v;
        /* R.layout.fragment1 only contains a TextView. */
    }
}
```

For the 2nd Fragment, I want to extend a FragmentActivity as shown below.

```
public class Fragment_2 extends FragmentActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment2);
        }
}
```

The 3rd Fragment is same as the first one.

But when I launch the app, it crashes. So, am I wrong in extending FragmentActivity for the class Fragment_2? Is it illegal to extend a FragmentActivity or even an Activity to fragment classes? If not, what is the problem here?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** After @CommonsWare's answer I updated my class as follows:

```
public class Fragment_2 extends SherlockFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend); //Error at this line
            //some error free code
            FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //Error at this line
        }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

My final two questions are:

1. How should I access my R.id.bSend Button in the Fragment_2 class.
2. Eclipse is giving the suggestion to change getSupportFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager(). Is that change all right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it illegal to extend a FragmentActivity or even an Activity to fragment classes?

`Fragment` is a Java class. Your fragment implementations (for use as pages in your `ViewPager`) must inherit from `Fragment`, directly or indirectly.

`Activity` does not inherit from `Fragment`. `FragmentActivity` does not inherit from `Fragment`. Hence, you cannot inherit from `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` and somehow *also* inherit from `Fragment`.

Comment: @BornAgain: You can have `Fragment_2` inherit from `Fragment`. Note that you have never explained why you "want to extend a FragmentActivity".

Comment: The problem being that inside the class Fragment_2, I need to use setContentView(), for which I need to extend either Activity or FragmentActivity. But that isn't possible.

Comment: @BornAgain: "I need to use setContentView()" -- no, you do not, as that is not possible from a `Fragment`. Use `inflate()` from `onCreateView()` as you did in `Fragment_1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it. But now I am facing two more problems. I would be very helpful if you took a look at my updated question.

Comment: @BornAgain: Delete your `onCreate()` method. Move the `Button` logic into `onCreateView()`, after `inflate()`, by calling `findViewById()` on `v` to find the `Button` in the inflated `View`. And I have no idea why you are messing with a `FragmentTransaction` from within a fragment.